# NGINX deny directory access except one php file

Tags: wordpress, nginx

Hi i want to allow access

```
wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
```

but deny access to

```
wp-admin/
```

Please help how i can do this. My current code

```
location /wp-admin/ {
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny all;
    }
```

Fall back location code

```
location @fallback {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8080 /;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        access_log off;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Nginx will use the more specific location, so you can just add another

```
location /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php {
# ...
}
```

See [the docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for all options.

Comment: Thanks but instead of executing php file it started downloading.

Comment: Well you still have to add the config regarding what should happen in that location, e.g. pass the request on to a backend, to fpm etc pp.

Comment: Can you give some hint?  I am newbie to NGINX. Can you give full code?

Comment: It depends on how your setup looks. It will most likely use whatever you do in your `location /`.

Comment: In my location code is following  `code location / {
  location ~ [^/]\.ph(p\d*|tml)$ {
   try_files /does_not_exists @fallback;
  }
  location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|mp3|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar|swf)$ {
   try_files $uri $uri/ @fallback;
   expires 30d;
  }
  location / {
   try_files /does_not_exists @fallback;
  }
 } `

Comment: Im guessing the fallback-location does the magic. What's in there?

Comment: location fallback is added in question. Please take a look.

Comment: You can just use `try_files /does_not_exists @fallback;`, as in your `location /`.